# Creating Tabmenu in j2me

Tags: java-me, canvas, tabs, midp, lcdui

Is there any way to create a Tab Menu in j2me?
I found a code but I am unable to understand it

In this code there is Tab Menu created which is in Canvas class and then Tab menu is created which is totally done in Canvas or painted. The only part I found difficult to grasp was the `void go()` method and then

When I try to draw anything above and below this code using paint method, it doesn't work - what's the problem?

Below is the code

```
// Tab Menu CANVAS class


  import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
  import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
public class TabMenuCanvas extends Canvas
{
    TabMenu menu = null;

    public TabMenuCanvas()
    {
        menu = new TabMenu(
            new String[]{"Home", "News", "Community", "Your files", "Credits", "Events", "Blog", "Upload", "Forum Nokia"}, 
            getWidth() - 20
        );
    }

    protected void keyPressed(int key)
    {
        int gameAction = getGameAction(key);

        if(gameAction == Canvas.RIGHT)
        {
            menu.goRight();

            repaint();
        }
        else if(gameAction == Canvas.LEFT)
        {
            menu.goLeft();

            repaint();
        }
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.translate(10, 30);

        menu.paint(g);

        g.translate(- 10, - 30);
    }
}


// Tab Menu Class 
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Font;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
public class TabMenu
{
    int background = 0xffffff;

    int bgColor = 0xcccccc;
    int bgFocusedColor = 0x0000ff;
    int foreColor = 0x000000;
    int foreFocusedColor = 0xffffff;
    int cornerRadius = 6;
    int padding = 2;
    int margin = 2;
    Font font = Font.getDefaultFont();

    int scrollStep = 20;

    int selectedTab = 0;    //selected tab index
    int[] tabsWidth = null; //width of single tabs
    int[] tabsLeft = null;  //left X coordinate of single tabs
    int tabHeight = 0;      //height of tabs (equal for all tabs)
    String[] tabs = null;   //tab labels
    int menuWidth = 0;      //total menu width

    int viewportWidth = 0;  //visible viewport width
    int viewportX = 0;      //current viewport X coordinate

    public TabMenu(String[] tabs, int width)
    {
        this.tabs = tabs;

        this.viewportWidth = width;

        initialize();
    }
    void initialize()
    {
        tabHeight = font.getHeight() + cornerRadius + 2 * padding; //[ same for all tabs]

        menuWidth = 0;

        tabsWidth = new int[tabs.length];
        tabsLeft  = new int[tabs.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < tabsWidth.length; i++)
        {
            tabsWidth[i] = font.stringWidth(tabs[i]) + 2 * padding + 2 * cornerRadius;

            tabsLeft[i] = menuWidth;

            menuWidth += tabsWidth[i];

            if(i > 0)
            {
                menuWidth += margin;
            }
        }
    }
    public void goRight()
    {
        go(+1);
    }
    public void goLeft()
    {
        go(-1);
    }
    private void go(int delta)
    {
        int newTab = Math.max(0, Math.min(tabs.length - 1, selectedTab + delta));

        boolean scroll = true;

        if(newTab != selectedTab && isTabVisible(newTab))
        {
            selectedTab = newTab;

            if( (delta > 0 && tabsLeft[selectedTab] + tabsWidth[selectedTab] > viewportX + viewportWidth) || 
                (delta < 0 && tabsLeft[selectedTab] < viewportX))
            {
                scroll = true;
            }
            else
            {
                scroll = false;
            }
        }
        if(scroll)
        {
            viewportX = Math.max(0, Math.min(menuWidth - viewportWidth, viewportX + delta * scrollStep));
        }
    }
    private boolean isTabVisible(int tabIndex)
    {
        return tabsLeft[tabIndex] < viewportX + viewportWidth &&
            tabsLeft[tabIndex] + tabsWidth[tabIndex] >= viewportX;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int currentX = - viewportX;

        g.setClip(0, 0, viewportWidth, tabHeight);

        g.setColor(background);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, viewportWidth, tabHeight);

        for(int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        {
            g.setColor(i == selectedTab ? bgFocusedColor : bgColor);

            g.fillRoundRect(currentX, 0, tabsWidth[i], tabHeight + cornerRadius, 2 * cornerRadius, 2 * cornerRadius);

            g.setColor(i == selectedTab ? foreFocusedColor : foreColor);

            g.drawString(tabs[i], currentX + cornerRadius + padding, cornerRadius + padding, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);

            currentX += tabsWidth[i] + margin;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to draw anything above and below this code using paint method, it doesn't work

what of the `paint` methods you use to draw *above and below*? Pay attention that there are **two** methods named that way - first is in TabMenuCanvas, second is in TabMenu (second method is invoked from TabMenuCanvas#repaint).

- whatever you would try to draw in `TabMenuCanvas#paint` will most likely be overwritten by *setClip and fillRect* when `TabMenu#paint` is invoked following repaint request

The only place where one can expect to be able to draw something visible seems to be in `TabMenu#paint` method, inside the clip area that is set there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUI Libraries for J2ME,for example [Lightweight User Interface Toolkit (LWUIT)](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/),[Flemil](http://flemil.com/) have "tab menu".You can see list of GUI Libraries [here](http://newsofthefuture.net/index.php?/archives/33-Evaluation-GUI-libraries-for-J2ME.html).